# Adding text between listboxes items

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I'm using vb.net form.

I have 8 listboxes (listbox1 , listbox2,listbox3..) each one contains many items and another empty listbox (listbox10). I'm trying to add first listboxes items into the listbox10

ex: )  listbox1 first items is 'A' , listbox2 first items is 'b' , listbox3 first items is 'c'...etc . Now listbox10 first item must be "Abc..."

The problem is i want to add text ( string or number) between each listbox

ex:)listbox1 first items is 'A' , listbox2 first items is 'b' , listbox3 first items is 'c'...etc . Now I want listbox10 first item to be "The letters ABC is now done"

The main idea is to combine all listboxes items and adding text between them to create a meaningful sentence

here is my code

```
Dim controls = New List(Of ListBox)() From _
{ListBox1, ListBox2, ListBox3, ListBox4, ListBox5, ListBox6, ListBox7, ListBox8}
    Dim minCount = Controls.Min(Function(x) x.Items.Count)
    For x = 1 To minCount - 1
        ListBox10.Items.Add(String.Join(" ", controls.Select
        (Function(lb) lb.Items(x).ToString)))
    Next

End Sub
```

Where i must to add my (string)?

Comment: You say "between each listbox", but your example "The letters is ABC" just puts text in front of the string.  Unclear what you want with that example.  If you just want the lead text: `ListBox10.Items.Add("The letters is " & String.Join(...`

Comment: @LarsTech no that was just example sir .. i want to add alot of diffrent text between each listbox in different places

Comment: Now you just want text before and after the letters?  I'm trying to figure out what's going between the letters...

Comment: for example listbox1 first items is 'A' , listbox2 first items is 'b' , listbox3 first items is 'c'...etc . Now I want listbox10 first item to be "The letter A is the letter before B now done C"

Comment: If it's going to be different text between the items, then you will have to lose the string.join and loop through your listbox collection.  Your for-loop is wrong, btw, it should be `0 to minCount - 1`

Comment: About for loop - i want to start from 1 , but can u be more clear about how loop through the listbox collection?

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to put different text between the listbox items, you would have to drop the String.Join function and loop through the ListBoxes yourself:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
For i As Integer = 0 To controls.Count - 1
  For j As Integer = 1 To minCount - 1
    sb.Append(controls(i).Items(j).ToString)
  Next
  If i < controls.Count - 1 Then
    sb.Append(" " & i.ToString & " ")
  End If
Next
ListBox10.Items.Add(sb.ToString)
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind support , but where to add my listboxes ? and where to add the customized text before or after each listbox??

Comment: @bod Your controls array already contained the ListBoxes, so I used your example.  Replace the `sb.Append(" " & i.ToString & " ")` line with whatever text you want.  It's still unclear to me what you are doing there.

Comment: I simply mean if with the same example i want to add "hi" before listbox1 and " hello" before listbox4 and "please" after listbox7 ... etc ... The main idea is to combine all listboxes items and adding text between them to create a meaningful sentence

Comment: @bod You could put a `Select Case i` inside the loop and put in text for every loop.  Or create another array of "sentences" to use for each ListBox.  But you might be better off just getting rid of the control loop and just create your sentence for every ListBox.

Comment: Can you add a simple example of how to to insert the select case inside the loop?